# Inconsistent margins in responsive row of divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm building a card-based layout. It goes from 5-4-3-2-1 items per row responsively. The page responds appropriately, but I'm having a difficult time with the margins for each card.

If I make margin: 1px; to create space between elements, it creates huge gaps instead of a small margin. In the current state, the margins are only correct on the 1 and 3-item views. All of the others run the margins together. I've been experimenting and wherever I add the margin, it creates the excessively large gap.

Tips? Suggestions? Is there a fatal flaw in place?

Thanks!

codepen: http://codepen.io/abrite/pen/gMaPPG

HTML for each card:

```
 <div class="item">
  <div class="cardheading">
    <h1>Alabama</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the codepen provided, the cards are in rows of 5, so 5-5-5-1, instead of 5-4-3-2-1 - is that an error? Or on purpose?

Comment: And adding `margin: 1px;` to `.item` changes it to 4-4-4-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your box widths are allowing for margins. 5 x 20% = 100%. 4 x 25% = 100%, and etc.

You need to reduce the box widths and specify margin left or right to allow for spacing between, for example: 5 x 18% = 90% + 5 x margin-left 1% and margin-right 1% = 100%.

There are two ways to achieve what you want, either through using Flexboxes, or by using Nth-child declarations which would help add margin to just one side of a box when it is the first or last box in the row, so that the row stretches to full width.

The latter could get particularly messy in multiple media queries, so I'd probably choose the former. There's plenty of tutorials online for flexboxes.

Here's 2 places to start:

http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what huge gaps you're referring to here, but adding margin: 1px; to each card will add a 1 pixel margin to every side of the card. If you have 2 card next to each other, each with a 1 pixel margin, you will get a 2 pixel margin between the cards. If you only want a 1 pixel margin total, you should do something like margin-right: 1px for each card, which will create a total gap of 1px between the cards.